# How to speed up STAN when fitting a random effect model on a large, sparse dataframe?

Tags: r, stan

I'm trying to fit a random effect model using RSTAN. My design matrix has 198 columns. It's so wide because my original dataframe is a bunch of factor variables, which I convert to binary indicators in order to try to fit the model in STAN. I'm able to fit models with a few columns converted from one or two predictors, but it has taken 10 hours to complete 1/2 of the samplings.

Here is the STAN code which I'm using to try to fit the model (basic linear model). I've tried to vectorize, but maybe there's a way to optimize further? Also, what is the intuition behind why it is taking so long?

```
     data {
      int<lower=0> N;
      int<lower=0> J; 
      int<lower=0> K;
      int<lower=1,upper=J> geo[N];
      matrix[N,K] X;
      vector[N] y;
    }
    parameters {
      vector[J] a;
      vector[K] B;
      real mu_a;
      real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_a;
      real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_y;
    } 
    model {
      vector[N] y_hat;
      for (i in 1:N)
        y_hat[i] <- a[geo[i]];
      mu_a ~ normal(0, 1);
      a ~ normal(0, 1);
      y ~ normal(mu_a + sigma_a * y_hat + X * B, sigma_y);
    }
```

Comment: 196 predictors, by itself, should not be a problem, although it is inadvisible without priors. There are various ways to optimize a linear model, but it isn't clear what problem you are facing. What do you mean by "crash"? Memory error, unable to initialize, stack overflow, etc.?

Comment: Apologies: I am actually fitting a model with a random effect. I've updated the code. Rstudio said it had lost connection with R yesterday, but when I fit it today it worked, but it's proceeding incredibly slowly, so my question now is: what I can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 8):

The question of what can you do to speed this model up is intertwined with the question of how can it be sampled more efficiently. The intuition as to why it is taking so long may have to do with the prior dependence between `a` and `sigma_a` (and to a lesser extent `mu_a`).

1. When `sigma_a` is small for some iteration, the elements of `a` have to be close to `mu_a`
2. When `sigma_a` is large for some iteration, the elements of `a` can be far from `mu_a`.

Since Stan only has one stepsize parameter to manipulate, it can be difficult to find a stepsize that is appropriate in both situations. At best, you get a stepsize that is small enough to preserve accuracy in the former case but the walltime will be adversely affected because it has to take many leapfrog steps with a small stepsize in the latter case.

For models like these, we generally recommend reparameterizing like

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  int<lower=0> J; // 47 apparently but don't hardcode it
  int<lower=1,upper=J> geo[N];
  vector[N] y;
}  
parameters {
  vector[J] a;
  real mu_a;
  real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_a;
  real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma_y;
} 
model {
  vector[N] y_hat;
  for (i in 1:N)
    y_hat[i] <- a[geo[i]];
  mu_a ~ normal(0, 1);
  a ~ normal(0, 1);
  y ~ normal(mu_a + sigma_a * y_hat, sigma_y);
}
```

Comment: Don't understand how this reparametrization is the same. You're adding mu_a, to sigma_a*y_hat?

Comment: What exactly is the random effect?

Comment: The way you had it originally, the elements of `y` were normal with mean `y_hat` and the elements of `y_hat` were normal with mean `mu_a` and standard deviation `sigma_a`. The same is implied if the elements of `y_hat` are standard normal but scaled by `sigma_a` and shifted by `mu_a` to form the mean for the elements of `y`. Perhaps `y_hat` should be renamed though.